# Edit dialog graphic glitch

Tags: bug, status-declined

In a question, I wanted to edit something but there was an existing edit. I got the review dialog (with a message stating that I already maxed out my edits). But there is this strange graphic glitch on the place where I guess an X should appear.

[image: rendering bug]

Seen on latest Chrome beta version (55.0.2883.75).

Comment: How consistent is this for you? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: @Qix It's a little hard to test, because I have to constantly search for posts with edits that are not yet reviewed, but so far it has been consistent every time I open these dialogs (on 2 separate questions). Tried clearing cache etc., still happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beta browsers are not supported.

See [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)

Comment: Fair enough. I tried to replicate in stable but so far I haven't had much luck on finding a post with a pending edit.

Comment: This is good to know; makes sense.

Comment: @gpgekko - if you do find the same with stable, that's something we can look at. Beta browsers? All bets are off ;)